# Using stringr for conversion of character object to numeric object

Tags: r, stringr

I'm trying to convert a character object displaying numbers into its appropriate numeric form. Some of the object's values resemble numbers with written numbers, e.g. '10.5 million' and '1.235 billion'. The problem is that the number of decimals of the actual numbers preceding the written-out numbers varies from value to value.

Ex: 69.40 million, 70.1 million, 12 million etc.

How do I in an easy way convert the written out number to an actual number so it matches the actual conceptual number?

I'm working with this code trying to clean up the gross_domestic column of the two tables, but I can't figure out how to finish this so that it is all numeric:

```
library(pacman)
pacman::p_load(httr, tidyverse, rvest, janitor)

grconurl <- "https://www.conservapedia.com/Essay:Greatest_Conservative_Movies"
woliburl <- "https://www.conservapedia.com/Essay:Worst_Liberal_Movies"


grcon <- read_html(grconurl)
wolib <- read_html(woliburl)

grcon_tabel <- grcon %>%
  html_node(".wikitable") %>% 
  html_table(., fill = T) %>% 
  clean_names()

wolib_table <- wolib %>%
  html_node(".wikitable") %>% 
  html_table(., fill = T) %>% 
  clean_names()

grcon_tabel$gross_domestic <- grcon_tabel$gross_domestic %>% 
  str_replace(
    pattern = ',',
    replacement = ('')) %>% 
  str_replace(
    pattern = '\\$',
    replacement = ('')
  ) %>% 
  str_replace(
    pattern = '\\[[:digit:][:digit:]]',
    replacement = ('')
  )
```

Comment: I'm getting 403 errors from your URLs.  Any chance you can provide a more minimal example, e.g. a list of strings and the desired output? Do you want the result of translating "$69.40 million" to be 69.4 or 6.94e7 ?

Comment: Mi desired output is the full numbers, i.e. for 69.9 million that would be 69900000 (so that I can compute t-test on differences in mean etc.). The problem is that I have very different strings, e.g. 69,9 million, 23,45 million, 124,3 billion and so on, which vary on decimals. I'm looking for a way to account for these decimal differences?

Comment: does my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library("tidyverse")
```

### example data

(using some of the values from your URL)

```
vals <- c("$34,543,701", "$69.40 million","$1.519 billion","junk")
dd <- tibble(vals)
```

### transform

```
(dd 
  %>% mutate(vals=str_remove_all(vals,"(,|\\$|\\[.*\\]|\\(.*\\))",   ## strip extraneous chars
             multiplier=ifelse(str_detect(vals,"million"),1e6,
                          ifelse(str_detect(vals,"billion"),1e9,1)),
             vals=str_remove(vals,"(m|b)illion"),   ## drop words
            vals=as.numeric(vals)*multiplier)
  %>% select(-multiplier)                           ## drop auxiliary variable
)
```

I intentionally left a non-numeric value in the example (since such values exist in the example you gave); this will trigger a warning from `as.numeric()`.  You could use `suppressWarnings()` around that particular element in the pipe ...

Comment: I would just suggest adding a little to the `str_remove_all` pattern so it is `"(,|\\$|\\[.*\\]|\\(.*\\))"`.  The full set of values has some notes between square brackets or parenthesis.

Comment: Thank you so much guys. Your input has been very helpful!